# Using Gstreamer Rust plugins from Android app

Tags: android, rust, gstreamer, rtp

I want to use gst-plugins-rs (in particular rtpav1depay) in Android app.

I am using either the standard binaries provided by gstreamer website (1.22) and a cerbero compiled version (1.23 with RUST variant enabled).

The tutorials (from 1 to 5) are all working well without issues in Android 11 and 13 (Android API 33) arm64-v8a. Only when using gst_parse_launch with rtpav1depay things go wrong:
`gst/parse/grammar.y:570:gst_parse_element_make no element "rtpav1depay"`
and in frontend app `Unable to build pipeline: no element "rtpav1depay"`

This is the jni/Android.mk relevant part:

```
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0 gobject-2.0
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS      := -liconv
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Also library libgstrsrtp is not present inside lib/gstreamer-1.0

May be related to unresolved https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/-/issues/381

> gst-plugins-rs ships plugin pkgconfig files in the wrong place, since cargo doesn't support custom dirs